# 'Invalid request: method is unavailable without access token'

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

При попытке повторить действия [Олега Молчанова](https://youtu.be/4EEhY35VPOY?t=646) <strike>вместо того,чтобы писать свои уроки и быть вторым Олегом</strike>  на 10:46 я получаю такую ошибку :

```
{'error': {'error_code': 8, 'error_msg': 'Invalid request: method is unavailable without access token', 'request_params': [{'key': 'oauth', 'value': '1'}, {'key': 'method', 'value': 'wall.get'}, {'key': 'owner_id', 'value': '-106890139'}, {'key': 'count', 'value': '100'}, {'key': 'offset', 'value': '0'}]}}
```

В [доке](https://vk.com/dev/wall.get) написано :

> Этот метод можно вызвать с ключом доступа пользователя.

Чтобы понять как получить access_token - сделал аналогичные действия как [тут](https://artem-malcov.ru/stati_i_sovety/poluchenie-klyucha-dostupa-access_token-dlya-api-vkontakte).

Получив токен из 85 символов, добавил его в переменную *tokenzi*

```
import requests


def main():
    # https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_id=210700286&v=5.52
    group_id = '-14066877'  # retro_america
    tokenzi = токен из 85 символов
    r = requests.get('https://api.vk.com/method/wall.get', params={'oauth': tokenzi, 'owner_id': group_id, 'count': 100, 'offset': 0})
    print(r.json())



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Запустил и получаю ту же ошибку :

```
{'error': {'error_code': 8, 'error_msg': 'Invalid request: method is unavailable without access token', 'request_params': [{'key': 'oauth', 'value': 'токен из 85 символов'}, {'key': 'method', 'value': 'wall.get'}, {'key': 'owner_id', 'value': '-106890139'}, {'key': 'count', 'value': '100'}, {'key': 'offset', 'value': '0'}]}}
```

Что я делаю не так ?

Дополнительно :
Если войти в настройки приложения

То там есть пункты :

- Защищённый ключ
- Сервисный ключ доступа (который отличается от access_token)
- Состояние (Приложение отключено)

Может я не то вбиваю ?

Comment: передавайте параметр не `oauth`, a `access_token`

Comment: Где? oauth -- [протокол авторизации](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth)

Comment: Видимо, это какое-то скрытое служебное поле, которое передаёт _метод_ авторизации. Не могу найти сходу в документации это.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё, что вам нужно заменить

```
... 'oauth': tokenzi ...
```

на

```
... 'access_token': tokenzi ...
```

[Источник](https://vk.com/dev/api_requests)